# Python2 (str) byte string

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

Does anyone of you know how to change python2 (str) byte string to Unicode python3?

Here is my code:

```
    def scan_ip_worker(self):
    recheck_ip = False
    while self.scan_thread_count <= self.scan_ip_thread_num and self.running:
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            # work for idle and too many scan failures
            if (recheck_ip or \
                    self.scan_ip_thread_num == 1 and \
                    self.config.max_scan_ip_thread_num > 1) and \
                    self.check_local_network.is_ok():
                if self.good_ip_num >= self.max_good_ip_num * 0.6 and \
                        len(self.ip_list) >= self.max_good_ip_num * 0.9:
                    ip_str = self.get_ip(to_recheck=True)
                    if ip_str and self.check_local_network.is_ok(ip_str):
                        self.recheck_ip(ip_str, first_report=False)
                        time.sleep(self.scan_recheck_interval)
                        continue
                else:
                    self.adjust_scan_thread_num()
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.exception("scan_ip_worker recheck ip except:%r", e)
        finally:
            recheck_ip = False

        try:
            ip_str = self.ip_source.get_ip()
            # self.logger.debug("check ip:%s", ip)

            if not ip_str or ip_str in self.ip_dict:
                time.sleep(5)
                continue

            if not self.check_local_network.is_ok(ip_str):
                # self.logger.debug("scan_ip:%s network is fail", ip)
                time.sleep(5)
            result = self.check_ip(ip_str)
```

But it gives me an error:

***scan_ip_worker except:TypeError("'in ' requires string as left operand, not bytes")***

Comment: `ip_str.decode('utf-8')`?

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].**